# iOS-Download sqlite file from server and overwrite previous one

Tags: ios, sqlite, download

I'm new to the downloading process in iOS .. I would like to know how to download a file (.sqlite file) from server and overwrite the previous one which is already in the bundle.

Do I have to copy the old sqlite file to the app documents folder so that I can overwrite it? And if I copy it to the documents folder can anyone access it or is it protected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything stored in the application bundle is read-only, so yes you will have to copy your `.sqlite` file into the `Documents/` directory first. Then when you download a new version, you can overwrite the original version in the `Documents/` directory.

And the `Documents/` directory is part of the iOS application sandbox, so only your application will be able to read/write from/to here.

Comment: Thanks..but do you have any tutorials that can help me with downloading the file from url link to the documents folder?